# Java - Protected method cannot be accessed from a subclass

Tags: java, access-modifiers

- I have the following Foo class which has the main method in it.
- Foo has extended Nee.
- Foo class is in com.package1 and Nee class is in com.package2.
- The problem is I cannot access the protected method of Nee, from Foo
  class through its object. Why is that ?(where the theory says protected members can be accessed by subclasses or classes within the same package)

The Foo Class looks like below,

```
package com.package1;

import com.package2.Nee;

/**
  *
  * @author Dilukshan Mahendra
  */
public class Foo extends Nee{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nee mynee = new Nee();
        /* mynee.sayProtected(); This gives me a compile error,
                                 sayProtected() has protected
                                 access in com.package2.Nee
        */
    }

}
```

The Nee Class is like below,

```
package com.package2;

/**
 *
 * @author Dilukshan Mahendra
 */
public class Nee {



    protected void sayProtected(){

        System.out.println("I'm a protected method in Nee!");

    }



}
```

Comment: you're trying to access from another package.

Comment: protected members can be accessed within package or subclasses only by subclass object. In different package you can't access protected member by super class object

Comment: @AloneInTheDark yeah but its a subclass of Nee, which in the theory says that you can access a protected member within the same package or from a subclass outside the package

Comment: @Braj can you give me an example?

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra It just doesn't work that way. `Foo` can't access protected members on a `Nee`.

Comment: If you are clear that protected member can't accessed outside package then It doesn't matter where are you creating `Nee` class object to access its protected method either in its subclass or any where else. Its same thing. Only subclass know about protected member and can be accessed via subclass object.

Comment: @Braj Now I get the picture, You cannot call this protected member from a superclass object, but by subclass object if the protected member resides outside the package, Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As class `com.package1.Foo` and class `com.package2.Nee` are in two different packages so `Nee` class instance will not allow you invoke protected method of that class.

Create the instance `Foo` which is subclass of `Nee` then invoke the protected method,.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.sayProtected()
```

Comment: You probably meant  "com.package1.Foo and class com.package1.Nee"?

Comment: Oops! In fact you probably mean to say " com.package1.Foo and class com.package2.Nee", right?

Comment: Yes I am sorry :( @zEro

Comment: Plus for this answer.  Big Minus for JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

If you are clear that protected member can't accessed outside package without subclass then It doesn't matter where are you creating Nee class object to access its protected method either in its subclass or any where else. Its same thing. Only subclass know about protected member and can be accessed via subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

**members can be accessed by subclasses or classes within the same package.**
You are using two different packages.

Answer (score 0):

Protected allows access to the member *of the subclass*. Here, you're trying to access the protected member of `Nee` when protected only allows access of the protected member on `Foo`.